# onload trigger click based on php value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have the following code :

```
<a href="#x_table" {{ $service->specie == 'x' ? 'onload="click()"' : '' }} 
class="{{ $service->specie == 'x' ? 'active' : '' }}" 
id="xEditNavigator">PlaceHolder</a>
```

I have `{{ $service->specie == 'x' ? 'onload="click()"' : '' }}` on the anchor.

It should work but isn't, Is there any other way around ?

Comment: do you have a function called `click` or are you trying to click on the anchor?

Comment: There is no **onload** event handler for an anchor. Take a look to [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<a href="#x_table" class="{{ $service->specie == 'x' ? 'active' : '' }}" 
id="xEditNavigator">PlaceHolder</a>
```

Then, at the bottom of the `<body>`

```
<script>
      @if($service->specie == 'x') 
           document.getElementById('xEditNavigator').click();
      @endif
</script>
```

Also if you are using jQuery:

```
<script>
    @if($service->specie == 'x') 
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#xEditNavigator').click()
        })
    @endif
</script>
```

Comment: That's one way, I was looking for some built-in functionality.
Anyway thanks. It worked.